# I want to send an email to an email address that will send users via Telegram bot

Tags: python, java, email, smtp, telegram-bot

I want to implement this logic. The user enters his email, email subject, and email description into the bot. Then the bot processes this letter and sends it to Example@platform.gov.ru. The problem arises that to send a letter you need smtp_password, which is different from the regular mail password, maybe there are ways to get this password without requiring too much from the user?
Maybe there is a ready-made solution on Python or Java?

```
Tried different code like this
```

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def send_email(sender_email, recipient_email, subject, message):
    smtp_server = 'smtp.google.com'
    smtp_port = 587
    smtp_username = User_name
    smtp_password = User_password

    msg = MIMEText(message)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender_email
    msg['To'] = recipient_email

    try:
        with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port) as server:
            server.starttls()
            server.login(smtp_username, smtp_password)
            server.send_message(msg)
        print('Email sent successfully.')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Failed to send email. Error: {str(e)}')


sender_email = input('Enter your sender email: ')
recipient_email = input('Enter recipients address: ')
subject = input('Enter the subject of the message: ')
message = input('Enter message text: ')

send_email(sender_email, recipient_email, subject, message)
```

Comment: No, that's not allowed. You can't just send email from any random address the user enters. At least, not if you want it to arrive and not be blocked by all kinds of spam filters.

Comment: with your common credentials you may use his/her email string. i mean when you send email you may change sender name but not credentials.